# Auto-fill Invoice number on selecting generate Purchase Order in Vtiger CRM

Tags: php, vtiger

I think my question concerns with the following function in vtiger/moodules/Inventory/model/Record.php

```
function setRecordFieldValues($parentRecordModel) {
        $currentUser = Users_Record_Model::getCurrentUserModel();

        $fieldsList = array_keys($this->getModule()->getFields());
        $parentFieldsList = array_keys($parentRecordModel->getModule()->getFields());

        $commonFields = array_intersect($fieldsList, $mergeArray);
        foreach ($commonFields as $fieldName) {
            if (getFieldVisibilityPermission($parentRecordModel->getModuleName(), $currentUser->getId(), $fieldName) == 0) {
                $this->set($fieldName, $parentRecordModel->get($fieldName));
            }
        }
        if($this->getModuleName() == 'PurchaseOrder' && getFieldVisibilityPermission($parentRecordModel->getModuleName(), $currentUser->getId(), 'account_id') == 0) {
            $this->set('accountid',$parentRecordModel->get('account_id'));
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Question is still not clear... What you want to achieve and whats the issue? What you have tried?

Comment: in invoice page select any invoice number and then from the right cornor click on more and then select generate purchase order.On that purchaseorder page the tracking invoice no field is not auto fill.